# Disallow second login session

Tags: ajax, session, logout

I am trying to find a solution for 2 months now but unfortunately I came up with no results. I have a subscription based website which streams music. What customers basically buy is a "panel" where they are listening to music ***without the need to refresh*** the page. What I need is to disallow their account being logged in if it is already in use. I found many plugins that force the user to log out but this happens only if they refresh the page. It could also work if for example: A logs in. B logs in with the same account and at this time A is being automatically logged out (I guess with the use of Ajax). It's a bit weird that nobody needed this in the past. Anyone could help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mostly what I tried is to make the "panel" page reload with ajax (no refresh) so plugins I found take effect but had no luck.

Comment: How does your "panel page" work, exactly?

Comment: It has several stream channels and the client plays whatever he likes.

Comment: That tells me what it _does_. It does not tell me _how it works_.

Comment: It does nothing except containing the stream channels (players).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not finding anything is because WordPress does not use any form of "sessions". Login status information is not saved, or retrieved.

Logging into WordPress basically sets a cookie in your browser which is a single authentication point. It is the equivalent of a username and password, with encryption and a timeout, all in one cookie. Well, two cookies.

Regardless, WordPress is stateless. If you want to log somebody out when they switch to another location, you need code above and beyond anything WordPress core itself. Which probably means custom code for your use case.

So, define your case in great detail, and maybe somebody can help you devise a solution. Best scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me in WordPress:

```
add_filter( 'authenticate','one_session_per_user', 30, 3 );

function one_session_per_user( $user, $username, $password ) {
    $sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user->ID );
    $all_sessions = $sessions->get_all();
    if ( count($all_sessions) ) {
        $login_page  = home_url( '/mt-pages/login/already_login/' );
        wp_redirect( $login_page . "?login=false/already_login/" );
        exit;
    }
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Answers should be more than a code snippet. Please file an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/185446/edit) and explain why this would work. Also, to properly format code in your answer (or question), highlight it and click **{}** above the edit box.